# Weirdly shaded faces after triangulating

Tags: modeling, faces

I triangulated the faces from this particular part of my mesh using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and everything turned out ok, except these faces which ended up with weird shading.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what it is without seeing the topology of your mesh. Try setting object shading to *Smooth*.

Comment: I suggest recalculating the normals and re-clicking smooth shading as the new faces for some weird reason might not have gotten affected. You can also add a sub-surf modifier to get rid of them. Additionally, you could just delete the triangles and replace them with rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

This also might be caused by duplicate vertices on each other. Try to go to edit mode, select everything (clicking A), on the tools tab, click 'Remove Doubles', that might fix it. Although it is indeed hard to tell without seeing your mesh.